# Is there a way to get the keys of an interface where interface[key] is a type?

Tags: typescript, types

If I have this interface:

```
interface Interface {
  a: number
  b: number
  c: string
  d: string
  e: number[]
}
```

How would I get the keys of `Interface` where the type of the value in `Interface` is/extends a certain type? It's like `Pick<T, K>` but instead of returning the keys that match a type it returns the keys whose values match a type.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
type KeyOfWhereValueMatches<T, U extends U[keyof U]> = // ???
KeyOfWhereValueMatches<Interface, number> // 'a' | 'b'
KeyOfWhereValueMatches<Interface, string> // 'c' | 'd'
KeyOfWhereValueMatches<Interface, number[]> // 'e'
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```js
type KeyOfWhereValueMatches<
    T,
    U,
    S = { [key in keyof T]: U extends T[key] ? key : never; }
    > = S[keyof S]
```

How it works:
`T` is your interface, `U` is the type you want to get keys for.

`S` is a calculated type that runs through each key of the interface type. If U is assignable to the type of that key (i.e. `number extends Interface[b]`) then the new type of that field is a string literal of its key. If not, it's a never.

For `KeyOfWhereValueMatches<Interface, number>`, `S` will be equal to:

```
interface S {
    a: "a";
    b: "b";
    c: never;
    d: never;
    e: never;
}
```

Lastly, `S[keyof S]` uses [lookup types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to return the types for all the available keys in `S`. These will be either the string literals of the suitable keys, or `never`. Since `never` isn't a thing that happens, the lookup just returns the string literals.